# qué podría hacer?, lo que pasa es que al momento que doy en el botón guardar, me salta esa excepción de la foto

Tags: c#, formularios

[image: ****]

Lo que pasa es que no me guarda el registro en una tabla que se llama viaje, pero dicha tabla esta relacionada con otras dos, pero al llenar los campos que conforman la relación en este caso los IDs, me muestra esta excepción

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia la imagen por el código en formato texto. También intenta explicar con mayor detalle el problema, mostrando cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál es el comportamiento actual. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Jds Por eso estamos como estamos, pues creen que ya todos nacemos aprendidos y no se acuerdan de cuando también fueron novatos. Si uno pregunta es porque quiere aprender, no para que lo hagan sentir como miersh

Comment: Yo no veo nada de malo en el comentario que te dieron, lo único que se debió fueron sugerencias para que tu pregunta sea mejor y entendible

Comment: Y cual fue el problema que te hizo sentir mal, cuando se te comento que tu pregunta estaba mal formateada (porque una imagen es dificil de leer desde cualquier dispositivo) y luego se te guio a una pregunta que responde exactamente a tu problema? en que punto se te trato mal? por haberte cerrado la pregunta? eso no implica nada.